# How can I find the android log file?

Tags: java, android

I am using the command

```
Log.i(TAG, "Received a message");
```

But I am not able to find where it is outputted.
Can any body help me about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view it in eclipse in the debug environment, and you can use adb: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat

You can also download something like aLogCat on a device for looking at live logfile information.

Comment: To view it in Eclipse, you don't need to use the debug environment. The output should show up in the LogCat view (Window > Show View > LogCat) as long as the emulator is showing up in the Devices view. (If it isn't, then kill and restart the adb server.)

Comment: that's true, but I didn't know the right menus to show the view from the top of my head, and I knew it was in the debug, but you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the  `adb logcat` command from the console (if `adb` is in your  path).